# Multiple Database Files/Context ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My understanding is that a context connects to a database via a connection string specified in   web.config. When I create new scaffolds it creates new database .mdf files with a new connection string. I am coming from rails active record with one database and one connection string. So why does asp.net do it differently? Why have multiple database files?

Also I changed the connection string for the user model to my default site database called Toolsite to simplify things and put the users in the same db as everything else -

```
 public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("Toolsite")
    {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(Database.Connection.ConnectionString);

    }
```

and this caused a `Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'.` exception even though the table AspNetUsers exists in the database "ToolSite". Is there any other part in the server code that needs to change?

Comment: You should not have multiple databases; only one.  Please see this series of documentation that will show you the proper use of MVC 5, Entity Framework 6 using code-first database migrations http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/tutorial-series-updated-for-entity-framework-6-code-first-with-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: That makes more sense, thank you. It must be some switch in Visual Studio when creating scaffolding for CRUD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default MVC project scaffold has always been a pet peeve of mine. When you create a new MVC project with auth, you get a user model and an application context to wire it up. That's great, in one respect, because it lets you immediately run the project with no extra configuration. However, they stupidly decided to put the user model and the application context in the same .cs file, so it confuses developers not familiar with the setup into thinking that the two are intrinsically linked.

In reality, MVC applications are designed to have a single context, and you should actually add your models to the existing context created by the scaffold, rather than create a new, separate context. The only reason to have multiple contexts is if you're literally dealing with multiple databases, and then, only really because you're dealing with *existing* databases in addition to your application-specific database. In other words, you should only have a single context that is tied to migrations and then you may or may not have additional contexts that operate on a database-first basis. Once you understand that, it becomes far less confusing to work with a scaffolded project.

Comment: Yeah I just discovered this and coming from rails it made no sense. The rails code does not have any context code, just models linked to active record. Also since the application comes with a default context in the User model Account I pretty much have to use that one or configure it to another context?

Comment: Convention over configuration! Also thanks for the answer, cleared things up.